# Array go out of bounds in VB

Tags: arrays, vb.net, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm currently working on a program that will convert a string into "combined integer" (namely: from a string, it will be splitted into two characters at a time and then each character in each group will be converted into ASCII number. Then, the first character is multiplied by 256 (shift 8 bit to the left) and add second character. It must not eliminate/forget any character inside the string

Here is when the trouble really begin: it threw IndexOutOfRangeException

```
    Dim input As String = TextBox1.Text.PadLeft(1)
    Dim charArr As Char() = input.ToCharArray
    Dim intGroup As UShort
    Dim strout As String = ""

    For index = 0 To charArr.Length - 2 Step 2
        Dim i = index
        Dim a = charArr(i)
        Dim b = charArr(i + 1)

        intGroup = CByte(AscW(a)) * 256 + CByte(AscW(b))
        strout = strout + CStr(intGroup) + " "
    Next

    MsgBox(strout)
```

My guess was that I modify the `index` inside the loop which is 'forbidden'.

Any possible solution??

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think `input.Length + 1` is the correct upper bound for your loop?

Comment: not sure, I'm just having gut feeling that way

Comment: Think about it this way - ignoring the `step 2` for a moment - if you have a string of length 2, you're asking the for loop to access  *four* indexes (indexes 0, 1, 2 and 3). Does that seem in any way correct to you? When there are only two characters involved?

Comment: You're right. I thought it was that way to avoid the out of bounds exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something *like* this but I don't know how you want to deal with odd length strings:

```
For index = 0 To charArr.Length - 1 Step 2
    Dim a = charArr(index)
    Dim b = If(index=charArr.Length - 1, _
            <something to use for odd length strings>, _
             charArr(index + 1))

    intGroup = CByte(AscW(a)) * 256 + CByte(AscW(b))
    strout = strout + CStr(intGroup) + " "
Next
```

I don't know what you want to use, especially if you bear in mind that .NET strings (unlike, say, C strings) can perfectly well contain a character with ascii code 0, so just using `0` may leave you with ambiguous data, depending on how you're *using* this string that you're constructing.

But basically, it comes down to you needing to do some special handling for odd length strings, and no magic manipulation of the `for` loop parameters will avoid that fact - you either deal with them in the loop (as above) or use a shorter loop (`.Length - 2`) and perform a length check afterwards and deal with the final character that you missed in the loop separately.

Comment: This is close, but I managed to go my way:      If (input.Length Mod 2 = 1) Then
            input = input + Chr(0).ToString
        End If

Answer (score 0):

```
For index = 0 To input.Length - 2 step 2
```

array its zero based, so if the lenght = n, last element is arr[n-1]. 
for handle only odds element, the last element its arr[n-2].

Comment: I did that, but it would not count the last character if it was done in that manner

Comment: Probably your input mod 2 = 1.